# Do not insert a background picture into widget.setStyleSheet

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, background-image, stylesheet

run file code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocess, re, shlex, json, test_fon_cod, os, sys, random, threading, time, glob, math, help, http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error


class Ui_Frame(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, test_fon_cod.Ui_test_fon):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_Frame()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Running a file obtained by converting from a "ui" file via pyuic5.bat:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_test_fon(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(541, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(18, 21, 190, 154))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(E:\image\fon.png);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 541, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

He tried to load the picture differently, not how it does not work out.
At start, there is nothing to swear at, but also does not load

Answer (score 0):

Change the line of the module `test_fon_cod.py`

```
self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(E:\image\fon.png);")
```

on

```
self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(E:/image/fon.png);")
```

See: [Python 3 Quick Tip: The easy way to deal with file paths on Windows, Mac and Linux](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)

Your filesystem starts from a root directory, notated by a forward slash `/` on Unix and by a drive letter `C:/` on Windows.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> pathFile = Path("pythonw.exe").resolve()
>>> 
>>> pathFile
WindowsPath('E:/Python/pythonw.exe')
>>>
```

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import test_fon_cod

class Ui_Frame(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, test_fon_cod.Ui_test_fon):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_Frame()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

test_fon_cod.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_test_fon(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(541, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(18, 21, 190, 154))

        self.widget.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png);")  # <----
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 541, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

[image]

Comment: It did not help

Comment: @S.Nick change `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)` to `QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you

Comment: @S.Nick 
I recommend you explain your solution, a response that does not indicate anything smells like it is not quality, **try it** is not an answer that a user of your reputation can provide, read [answer] :) for example, you should indicate why it is better to use `E:/image/fon.png` than `E:\image\fon.png`